# Drag file into Access, how to check the file details?

Tags: vba, ms-access, drag-and-drop

I like to drag a file from Windows Explorer or an attachment from an Outlook mail into MS-Access.

I discovered already I can use the Access BoundObjectFrame (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835725.aspx) as a target to drag and drop files from the Windows Explorer.

And with the following code I see that something was dropped into the field:

```
Private Sub OLE1_GotFocus()
    Debug.Print "OLE1_GotFocus()"
    Debug.Print " OLE1.Value: " & OLE1.Value
End Sub
```

But the value is just some binary information.
I want to know the file name which was dropped or I want to read what is in the dropped file (i.e. a text file is dropped).

I looked at all the properties and searched on the internet but I did not find a solution. I would have guessed many people tried before what I want to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think the BoundObjectFrame will get you what you want.

I suggest using a [**ListView Control**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443482%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) instead, an ActiveX control. It has inbuilt Drag&Drop support.

**Demo:**

On a form, insert a `Microsoft ListView Control, version 6.0` ActiveX control.
Name it `lvwDD`.
In right-click, ListViewCtrl-object, Properties: set OLEDropMode to `1 - ccOLEDropManual`.

Insert this [event procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k6w4bah(v=vs.60).aspx):

```
Private Sub lvwDD_OLEDragDrop(Data As Object, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)

    Dim i As Long

    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244109(v=vs.60).aspx
    Const vbCFFiles = 15

    If Data.GetFormat(vbCFFiles) Then

        ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267471(v=vs.60).aspx
        For i = 1 To Data.Files.Count
            Debug.Print Data.Files(i)
        Next i

    Else
        Debug.Print "No file(s) dropped."
    End If

End Sub
```

Drag&Drop one or multiple files on the control, and see the output in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: Thanks, you earned the bounty.

Comment: Do you know how this could work with dragging an attachment from an Outlook email into this ListView control? I get the "No file(s) dropped" message. And if I try i.e. with "If Data.GetFormat(VbCFText)" this also does not work.

Comment: @Edgar: That's a very interesting question, but it seems to be extremely complicated: [Handling Drag and Drop of Email Attachments](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/email/article.php/c3381/Handling-Drag-and-Drop-of-Email-Attachments.htm) (linked from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8c4adf0a-2b72-4a4b-ba71-c61cabc6f5dd/drag-email-attachment-and-drop-to-listview-vba?forum=accessdev)). -- Or https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21786219/Ole-Drag-Drop-File-Attachment-From-Outlook.html

Comment: This looks good.  Once I drag & drop a file, how can I see it's original directory?  For example, if I want to modify it and save it with a new name in the original directory, how do I know what the original directory was?

Comment: `Data.Files(i)` contains the full path. You can get the directory e.g. with `Left(Data.Files(i), InStrRev(Data.Files(i), "\"))` @PowerUser

Comment: Just an FYI this exact code works on a Treeview control as well.