# Extract file location by dragging it into an Access form?

Tags: ms-access, drag-and-drop

Is there a way I can create an area in a MS form where, if I drag a file to it, it can extract the information of that file's location? So for example if I have file Test.txt in c:\Temp, and drag the file into the field, a variable can be set of "C:\Test.txt". I plan to use this to copy the file to a specific folder based on the form.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you google "Access drag and drop file name"? Expect answers that advise using FileDialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag file into Access, how to check the file details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083256/drag-file-into-access-how-to-check-the-file-details)