# No reaction when dragging into Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, drag-and-drop

This post [Drag file into Access, how to check the file details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083256/drag-file-into-access-how-to-check-the-file-details) says a BoundObjectFrame can be used as a target to drag and drop files from the Windows Explorer.

I've tried putting one on a form, but when I drag a file onto it, I get the circle-and-slash symbol that says I can't.

I've also tried various other control, including MS Forms textboxes, which are supposed to support drag-and-drop. But in every case I get the symbol.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Did you check the answer on that question?  ;)

Comment: I did. I can't use ListView because MS doesn't make one for 64-bit.