# Generate file with VBA on mouse down and allow user to drag file to explorer or another app

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there any way to generate a file on mousedown (of a button), that would then be attached to the curser the same way it would be if you clicked and dragged from explorer? allowing the user to basically drag and drop the "button" to an upload form in a browser?

I would assume the file would have to be generated and saved to a temp location, then the curser would be "passed" the file.

I am not looking for a final solution, just an answer about wether it is possible and maybe a lead on where to start, as I have tried searching but its not an easy thing to search for as all results point to dragging INTO excel/access.

Comment: Drag and drop support in Access is hardly existent, it only works with [special controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40130709/3820271). It may be possible to manually instantiate a drag event, but I strongly suggest to choose a different route.

Comment: @Andre I was hoping to avoid saving to a specific folder or asking for a save location and having the user have to open it to drag and drop to the web form.

I suppose i could have the code open explorer with the file selected once the file is saved, that would save a few clicks, the drag and drop was just a lot smoother.

Comment: *have the code open explorer with the file selected* -- yeah, that's what I would do. Most users will be quite happy with that. (Perhaps even more if you teach them that Ctrl+W closes the Explorer window.)